# what is the springframework version dependency in spring-kafka master

Tags: spring, dependency-management, spring-kafka

I'm getting the impression that spring-kafka 2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT requires a build snapshot of the basic spring framework in order to run. is this true?

When I run code compiled against it, it errors out during initialization due to a call to Assert(expr, Supplier), which doesn't exist in the most up to date release of springframework.  I have to look at the master branch to find a version of Assert.java that can take a Function instead of a string.  (called from MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:387 in spring-kafka)

The difference between

```
Assert.state(expr, String.format("error message: %s", myVar))
```

and

```
Assert.state(expr, () -> {
  return String.format("error message: %s", myVar);
});
```

is a pretty darn small optimization - especially in code that only executes during initialization rather than for every incoming message.  Would it not make sense to keep dependencies on unreleased code to an absolute minimum so that spring-kafka doesn't end up in the position of being unable to release because it relies on an unreleased version of springframework itself?

I don't mind a dependence on spring-kafka that is not quite released, since that's a small codebase that I can isolate within my own, if need be.  But if it forces a snapshot of the entirety of spring on me, there's no way I can consider using it, which means the project then doesn't benefit from bugs I uncover and/or fix on its way to production release.

Answer (score 0):

2.0.0 requires Spring Framework 5.0.

1.2.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT and 1.1.6.BUILD-SNAPSHOT are available for older Spring releases.

1.2.2 and 1.1.6 should be relased today.